Why is there an electric field but not magnetic field on the LHS of the integral form of Faraday's Law
Just started to learn Electromagnetism, and didn't quite understand, please help correct my misunderstanding:
The lectures said that the electromotive force (e.m.f), was
$$
{\cal E} = \oint \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}/q =-d\Phi_B/dt
$$
But, later in the text this transforms to:
$$
{\cal E} = \oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s} = -d\Phi_B/dt 
$$
Surely, the force can also be of magnetic nature, being ${\cal E} = \oint \vec{v} \times \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{s}$ ?
Why does the integral form only have the Electric Field on the left hand side, which represents the element of the force in the direction of displacement around the closed path, but not the Magnetic Field which also affects the force?
Thanks to Triatticus, now have changed the equations to have the closed loop integral.

You use $\vec{E}$ and E what is E?

The path integral symbol is \oint by the way for $\oint$.

According to the lectures, how $\vec F$ was defined?

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90, F was defined by Lorentz's Law, as in F = q times (E + v cross B)

@trula, E is electromotive force, while E with the vector is the electric field

The answer is that the notation you have used is not correct
It is true that
$\epsilon = - \frac{d \phi}{dt}$
It is not true in general that this is an electric field, in general:
$$\epsilon =\oint (\vec{E} + \vec{V}×\vec{B}) \cdot \vec{dl} = - \frac{d \phi}{dt}$$
What your lecturer has not made clear is that your right hand side should not be the rate at which the magnetic flux changes, as you are correct, this includes the motional emf caused by the magnetic force.
It should read :
$$\oint \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl} = -\iint \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} \cdot \vec{da}$$
This right hand side is different from the expression you gave, as the derivative is on the inside of the integral, these only coincide when the loop is unchanging, ie no magnetic force
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction
Look under 'proof', this page treats both magnetic and electric field contributions to faradays law, using the magnetic lorentz force, and the maxwell faraday equation( the one with only electric fields present)

He considers only EMF due to induced electric field. The emf depending on external magnetic field you find missing is called motional emf, and can be present only when a part of the circuit is moving. In short, he assumes a circuit where $\vec{v}=0$.
